# navbar changes background when scroll down, but doesnt change back when scrolled up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the JS code here:

```
  var fixmeTop = $('.navbar').offset().top;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
      var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {
          $('.navbar').css({
              position: 'fixed',
              top: '0',
              margin:'auto',
              background: 'white',
              color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
              padding: '10px'
          });
          $('li a').css({
              color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)'
          });
      } else {
          $('.navbar').css({
              position: 'static'
          });
      }
  });
```

The problem is, when i scroll down it does change. but when i scroll back up to the original position, it doesnt change back. I want the nav to change its background, padding and color when it goes down, but when its back to its original position (its the topbar, on top of the browser), it should change back to background:none, color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6) and padding:20px thanks.

this is the html

```
<div class="navbar">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.navbar{
    margin:auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding:20px;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li {
    display:inline-block;
}
li a {
    min-width:140px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    background: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:15px;
}
li:hover a {
    border-bottom:3px solid #EB9532;
}
```

Comment: add `background` on `.navbar`class its shows what you want

Comment: change the color in the `else` part of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset applied styles when you scroll back. In general, avoid using `css` method like this, as it's not very flexible. You can significantly simplify your code if you move styles to CSS and just toggle class name on navbar:

```
var $navbar = $('.navbar'),
    fixmeTop = $navbar.offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $navbar.toggleClass('fixed', currentScroll >= fixmeTop);
});
```

with CSS:

```
.navbar.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background: white;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    padding: 10px;
}

.navbar.fixed li a {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/fgm3yvL9/

Comment: when i give it a margin : 0 in the body (for top) so margin-top:0, it wont work. i really wnt that white space on the top. what should i do?

Comment: Sorrym, don't understand what element margin-top are you setting, and between what and what you want gap?

Comment: i have a margin : 0 on the body. When i get rid of it, it gives a small gap on the top. I dont know how to get rid of the margin at the top because when i give it a margin-top: 0 in the body, it disrupts the navbar jquery functions

Answer (score 0):

```
var fixmeTop = $('.navbar').offset().top;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
      var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {
          $('.navbar').css({
              position: 'fixed',
              top: '0',
              margin:'auto',
              background: 'white',
              color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
              padding: '10px'
          });
          $('li a').css({
              color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',

          });
      } else {
          $('.navbar').css({
              position: 'static',
              background:none, 
              color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6),
              padding:20px
          });
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Its has possible of two ways.,

1)you add `background` property on `.navbar` class in stylesheet

2)add `background` property in `else` part

like

```
.navbar{
    margin:auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding:20px;
    background: none;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
```

or

```
else {
          $('.navbar').css({
              position: 'static',
              background: 'none',
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change CSS values with jQuery, you will always have to change them back with jQuery. jQuery does not add a new class to your page. It appends its styling to the tag itself in the source. Inspect your navbar tag and then scroll down to see what I mean.

Since inline styling usually always takes priority, your navbar will never change back without either removing the CSS you added (with jQuery) or overwriting the CSS you added (with jQuery.)

I would recommend overwriting, as it's a lot simpler. You just need to add the opposite comparison with the initial CSS you want to apply. In this case, no background with slightly transparent text:

```
if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {
      $('.navbar').css({
          position: 'fixed',
          top: '0',
          margin:'auto',
          background: 'white',
          color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
          padding: '10px'
      });
      $('li a').css({
          color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)'
      });
  }
  if (currentScroll < fixmeTop) {
      $('.navbar').css({
          'background':'none',
          'color':'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)'
      });
    }
```

From personal experience I would suggest using the 'currentscroll < fixmetop' comparison. I've had nothing but problems with IE8 and not specifying the less than scroll (horizontal scrolling in particular.) Just make sure it behaves as you want it to.